# CodeIgniter Update Syntax?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to update my 'HM_Jobs' database, as far as I can tell from the manual this should work, however it doesn't update the database, any suggestions?

```
function amend_job($title,$description,$location,$date,$time,$pay,$jobcat,$job_id) //This function amends a job.//
{ 
    $amendJob=array(
    "JobTitle"=>$title,
    "JobDescription"=>$description,
    "JobLocation"=>$location,
    "JobDate"=>$date,
    "JobStartTime" =>$time, 
    "JobPay"=>$pay, 
    "JobCategory"=>$jobcat, 
    ); 


    $this->db->where('JobID', $job_id);
    $this->db->update('HM_Jobs', $amendJob);
}
```

Comment: After update, use `echo $this->db->last_query();` to print your last query then you can run the query manually to check where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Model:**

Suggestion: Send an array `$data` instead on sends each value separately.

Check that you have done the same as I've done below -

```
class Job_model extends CI_Model
{

    public $db;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db = $this->load->database('default',true);
    }

    public function amend_job($data, $job_id)
    {   
        $amendJob=array(
                          "JobTitle"=>$data['title'],
                          "JobDescription"=>$data['description'],
                          "JobLocation"=>$data['location'],
                          "JobDate"=>$data['date'],
                          "JobStartTime" =>$data['time'], 
                          "JobPay"=>$data['pay'], 
                          "JobCategory"=>$data['jobcat'] 
                    ); 

                    $this->db->where('JobID', $job_id);
                    $this->db->update('HM_Jobs', $amendJob);
    }
}
```

**Try debugging:**

1) print both the values passed to the function.

```
echo $job_id.'<br><pre>'; print_r($data);
```

2) if values are correct, try printing the query.

```
echo $this->db->last_query();   // after update query
```